# Upgrading SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I have a problem when upgrading Sugarcrm from 6.2 to 6.3 version. When I upgrade a local Sugarcrm installation it works but when I start upgrading my Sugarcrm 6.2 site and uploading the upgrade package it doesnt upload.

The same thing works on local server rather than the remote server of same version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the in-app upgrade wizard, perhaps this blog post may help...

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/04/27/howto-get-around-file-upload-size-limit-issues/

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade wizard has lot of limitation. Try silent upgrader. That will help